# In which episode does Kakashi think Naruto is his sensei?

Tags: naruto

In what episode does Kakashi thinks Naruto is his sensei Minato? Not the one in shuriken training, but the one on battlefield. The song *My Name* started playing and I remember the scene being so badass.

Answer (score 2):

The episode is #329 of *Naruto Shippūden*, titled "[Two-Man Team](http://www.crunchyroll.com/naruto-shippuden/episode-329-two-man-team-627393)". It's manga equivalent is Chapter 571, "Tailed Beast Mode!!". The scene you're referring to is at 08:05.

Kakashi mistakes Naruto to be his former sensei right after Naruto deflects the five Tailed Beast Balls with astonishing speed.

Here's the scene from the manga:

[image]